# GIT-TF Invalid path: */.git

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I would like to move from TFS to Git. I downloaded GIT-TF tool. I was successfully able to move one project, but when I try the other one I get an error.

Problem is that in this TFS project there is small part (one folder) that is already under git (I have no idea why, but it is some legacy project, so who knows).

When I run **git-tf clone https://******

I get

**git-tf: Invalid path: Thinktecture.IdentityServer-GitHub/.git**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to clone the project if you delete the folder? I've tried your scenario, but couldn't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, I am able to clone the project if I delete the .git folder. Not sure how to reproduce the issue as this only happens to one specific project and not to all folders which are under git.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my test steps for your reference:

1. I created a project `testgit` in a TFVC project, then add a folder `test` which is under git.

[image]

2. perform `git-tf clone`, and clone the project successfully:

[image]